# How to convert custom filter from HBase 0.94 to HBase 0.98 that doesnt use any protos?

Tags: java, hbase

I am getting timeouts with the error appearing to come from my custom filter. Error below:

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.DeserializationException: parseFrom called on base Filter, but should be called on derived type
```

I see that write and readFields are no longer supported in Hbase 0.98. Currently, my methods for write and readFields are as follows:

```
 public MyCustomFilter(Schema first) {
     this.schema = first;
     filterNow();
 }

public void write(DataOutput o) throws IOException {
  byte[] firstBytes = Bytes.toBytes(first.toString());
  out.writeInt(firstBytes.length)
}

public void readFields(DataInput i) throws IOException {
  int firstLength = i.readInt();
  byte firstBytes = new byte[firstLength];
  i.readFully(firstBytes, 0, firstLength);
  this.first = new Schema.Parser().parse(new ByteArrayINputStream(firstBytes);
  filterNow();
}

private void filterNow() {
   FilterQueryParser parser = new FilterQueryParser(first);
   ....
}
```

Cloudera seems to think its just a matter of migrating these methods:

```
FilterBase no longer implements Writable. This means that you do not need to implement readFields() and write() methods when writing your own custom fields. Instead, put this logic into the toByteArray and parseFrom methods. See this page for an example.
```

However the sample provided of SingleColumnValueFilter appears to use ProtoBufs from Filter.Protos, which appears to contain a SingleColumnValueFilter that is core to HBase... My CustomFilter uses nothing of the sort, I use no protobufs at all.
Is there a way to convert what I have into what makes hbase 0.98 happy? O (Schema.parser is avro) r am I required to  use Filter.Protos now? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement the method `public byte[] toByteArray()` instead of `public void write(DataOutput o)` to serialize your filter instance on your client side to be sent to the HBase server side.

Similarly, you have to implement the method `public static Filter parseFrom(final byte[] pbBytes)` instead of `public void readFields(DataInput i)` so that the byte stream can be read on the server side and translated in an instance of your filter by HBase.

Unfortunately, it seems that we lost the useful objects DataInput and DataOutput which were available in 0.94. We now have to handle the raw byte array. For example to write a String instead of leveraging DataOutput.writeUTF and DataInput.readUTF, we have to "manually" write an int before the string in the byte array to know the number of bytes concerned by the coming String.

Anyway, doing my "manual" byte array handling for serializing and deserailizing the filter worked for a custom filter on HBase 1.0.2.